# Need better summation select statement in postgres function

Tags: postgresql, select

I've got two tables in my database.  One of them, 'orders', contains a set of columns with an integer which represents what the order should contain (like 5 of A and 15 of B).  The second table, 'production_work', contains those same order columns, and a date, so whenever somebody completes part of an order, I track it.

So now i need a fast way to know which orders are completed, and I'm hoping to avoid a 'completed' table on the first column as orders are editable and it's just more logic to keep correct.

This query works, but it's horribly written.  What's a better way to do this?  There are actually 12 of these columns that go into this query...I'm just showing 3 of them for the example.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM orders o
    WHERE ud = (SELECT SUM(ud) FROM production_work WHERE order_id = o.ident)
            AND dp = (SELECT SUM(dp) FROM production_work WHERE order_id = o.ident)
            AND swrv = (SELECT SUM(swrv) FROM production_work WHERE order_id = o.ident)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select o.*
from
    orders o
    inner join
    (
        select order_id, sum(ud) as ud, sum(dp) as dp, sum(swrv) as swrv
        from production_work
        group by order_id
    ) pw on o.ident = pw.order_id
where
    o.ud = pw.ud
    and o.dp = pw.dp
    and o.swrv = pw.swrv
```